# Locating My Files in Android 4.0.4

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, usb-connection-mode, file-management

I have bought a new Android phone (Intel Yolo Smartphone) and it runs on Android 4.0.4. However I can't seem to locate the My files (It is called that way in Android 2.3.6) folder so as to access the internal memory storage files.

In Android 4.0.4 the folder is called by which name?

Answer (score 1):

You can download ES File Explorer. It's a free file explorer for android.

[Download from Google Play](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&ei=uNuOUq72DezA7AaW_4CIDg&usg=AFQjCNFUmIA8kmgY6HqGvkT4zNmNee2U6w&sig2=VLkT3gpMGRFlh6oPVv_poQ&bvm=bv.56988011,d.ZGU)

It's quite easy to use and doesn't require root access.

Answer (score -1):

Look for a folder named `sdcard` using a file explorer app.